# Download file using putty ssh

Tags: ssh, putty

I need to download a file using putty. But trying psftp says that it isn't installed (even though I've downloaded and installed everything but puttytel).

Ideas?

Comment: Use WinSCP instead?

Comment: What error do you get when you run psftp.exe? Remember that it's a standalone executable, not invoked from within putty itself

Comment: I'll use WinSCP instead. I was hoping to use putty, since its closer to linux, but winscp should do just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fsftp to work from the windows command line using the psftp command, the location of psftp needs to be in the [path](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm).

If you don't want to do that, you can run psftp from the start menu and it will open up in the command prompt for you. You'll have to use sftp [commands](http://www.cs.unc.edu/help/sftp/commands.html) like open, put, get, and quit to accomplish anything.

As Daniel Beck said, [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) is a decent replacement. I personally prefer the [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) client. You can use quick connect, just make sure to point it at port 22.